# Sinon fake server not intercepting requests

Tags: node.js, sinon

Trying to use Sinon for the first time because of its fake server functionality that lets me stub an API response. Test itself is written for Mocha

However, the fake server doesn't seem to be intercepting the requests.

Code:

```
describe('when integrated', function() {

    var server;
    beforeEach(function() {
        server = sinon.createFakeServer();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        server.restore();
    });


    it('can send a message to the notification service', function() {
        server.respondWith("POST", new RegExp('.*/api/notificationmanager/messages.*'),
            [200, 
                { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                '{ "messageId":23561}'
            ]);

        var messageOnly = new PushMessage(initMessageObj);
        var originalUrl = PushMessage.serverUrl;
        messageOnly.setServerAPI("http://a.fake.server/api/notificationmanager/messages");
        console.log("fake server is: ", server);
        messageOnly.notify()
            .then(function(response) {
                messageOnly.setServerAPI(originalUrl);
                return response;
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                response.should.be.above(0);
            })
        console.log(server.requests);
        server.respond();
    })
});
```

For reference, `PushMessage` is an object that has a static property `serverUrl`. I'm just setting the value to a fake URL & then resetting it.
The `notify()` function makes a post message using `request-promise-native` to the `serverUrl` set in the PushMessage's static property.

What seems to be happening, is that the `POST` request ends up being properly attempted against the URL of `http://a.fake.server/api/notificationmanager/messages`, resulting in an error that the address doesn't exist...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong...? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several issues on the Sinon GitHub repository about this. Sinon's fake server:

> Provides a fake implementation of XMLHttpRequest and provides several interfaces for manipulating objects created by it.
>
> Also fakes native XMLHttpRequest and ActiveXObject (when available, and only for XMLHTTP progids). Helps with testing requests made with XHR.

Node doesn't use XHR requests, so Sinon doesn't work for this use case. I wish it did too.

Here's an issue that breaks it down: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1049

Nock is a good alternative that works with Node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock

Comment: Gah. Never thought to google fake server & node together... Thanks!